# App Bar Transition with Scaffold in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, transition, scaffold

The issue I'm encountering is that when transitioning between screens, the top app bar always appears first and doesn't follow the transition of the intended screen.

How do I make the top app bar of a scaffold follow the transition of a screen as shown in the [Gif?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORHuw.gif)

Here's my current [Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssfMB.gif), the app bar always appears first.

Code:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            NotesTheme {
                MainApp()
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MainApp(
    appNavController: NavHostController = rememberNavController()
) {
    val backStackEntry by appNavController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    val currentScreen = backStackEntry?.destination?.route
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            if (currentScreen == AppScreen.Add.route) {
                TopBar(
                    navigateUp = {
                        appNavController.navigateUp()
                    },
                    isActionsActive = false,
                    isActionsClick = {}
                )
            }
        },
    ) { innerPadding ->
        AppNavHost(appNavController = appNavController, modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding))
    }
}

// I've provided a longer transition duration to make the difference more noticeable
fun NavGraphBuilder.addGraph(
    appNavController: NavHostController
) {
    composable(
        route = AppScreen.Add.route,
        arguments = AppScreen.Add.navArguments,
        enterTransition = {
            slideIntoContainer(
                AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Start, tween(1000)
            )
        },
        exitTransition = {
            slideOutOfContainer(
                AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.End, tween(1000)
            )
        },
        content = {
            AddScreen(appNavController = appNavController)
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Could you edit your post and include a video of how your current animation looks like? Also you could include the code that you currently have.

Comment: Thank you! I've revised my post to include both the code and a gif showcasing the current animation of my application. @BenjyTec

Comment: Thanks for updating your post! I posted an answer below. If it helps to resolve the issue, you can mark is as accepted answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. I hope this helps you! Feel free to ask if something is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You apply the animations within the `AppNavHost` Composable. So the animations will only be applied on the Composables that you display within the NavHost, and not to the Scaffold that is on the same level as the NavHost.

To apply the animation also to the Scaffold, you have to move the `topBar` of the Scaffold from the `MainApp` Composable into a separate Scaffold in the `AddScreen` Composable:

```
@Composable
fun MainApp(
    appNavController: NavHostController = rememberNavController()
) {
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
    ) { innerPadding ->
        AppNavHost(appNavController = appNavController, modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding))
    }
}
```

Then update your `AddScreen` Composable:

```
@Composable
fun AddScreen(appNavController: NavController) {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopBar(
                navigateUp = {
                    appNavController.navigateUp()
                },
                isActionsActive = false,
                isActionsClick = {}
            )
        }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        // ...
        // your content that you previously had in here
        // don't forget to apply innerPadding to the topmost Composable in here
    }
}
```

---

As a small side note, it is a cleaner approach not to pass the NavController into a Composable. Instead, implement a callback for handling back presses in the Composable:

```
@Composable
fun AddScreen(onBackPressed: () -> Unit) {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopBar(
                navigateUp = onBackPressed,
                isActionsActive = false,
                isActionsClick = {}
            )
        }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then handle it in the NavHost as follows:

```
content = {
    AddScreen(onBackPressed = { appNavController.navigateUp() })
}
```